# What is the use of chloroform in the procedure of determining peroxide value?

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox

In this [procedure](https://www.lubrizol.com/-/media/Lubrizol/Personal-Care/Documents/Literature/Test-Procedures/TP-AATM_516-01.pdf) of determining peroxide value, the oil sample is dissolved in acetic acid chloroform solution. I understand that the acid is added so that the following reaction occurs

$\ce{2ROOH + 2H^+ + 2I^- -> 2ROH + I2 + H2O}$.

But what is the point of the added chloroform?

Comment: Probably to help dissolve the sample - think vinegar/oil on salad, which is typically not really homogenous. The sample chemical would still react with the iodide due to the swirling of step 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acetic acid is required for this method for exactly the reason you gave.  It also has the fortunate property of being miscible with many polar *and* non-polar solvents.  Because this is a method for the analysis of oil samples, it is necessary to chose a non-polar solvent capable of dissolving the sample that is also miscible with the acetic acid.  Chloroform is one solvent that fits that description nicely.

As a quick side-note, the use of chloroform in this test procedure is actually now discouraged by the [Standard Methods for the Analysis of Oils, Fats and Derivatives](http://old.iupac.org/publications/books/ISBN0632033371_compress.pdf).  Isooctane seems to be the preferred solvent, apparently for health and safety reasons.